# How to 'talk' to USB modem in Linux?

Tags: 12.04, usb, modem

I have a USB modem that is identified in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) with `lsusb` as

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0572:1329 Conexant Systems (Rockwell), Inc.
```

How to talk to that device (e.g. with microcom etc?)? What `dev` device should I use? There is no `/dev/ttyUSBXXX` available and just one `/dev/ttyACM0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by talk you mean send AT commands in the form

```
echo "ATi" > /dev/usbDev
```

try this:
http://brunomgalmeida.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/send-at-commands-to-usb-modem/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: A reader program like `cat` should be used to get result of issued command. ie: `cat /etc/usbDev`

Answer (score 4):

You can use cu.

```
$ sudo apt-get install cu
```

You can connect to your modem with:

```
$ cu -l ttyACM0
```

(with: ttyACM0 being the device /dev/ttyACM0)
You should get a response:

```
connected
```

At this point you can use any of the standard AT commands such as to test dialing:

```
ATDT 123-456-7890
```

You should have your userid set to the group dialout for permission to access the modem.

You can exit the cu application with "~." (tilde dot).

You can find other Hayese commands at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set

Answer (score 2):

Use `minicom`, `socat` or `screen`:

```
socat - /dev/ttyUSB1 
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB1
screen /dev/ttyUSB1
```

NOTE: I used real device name `/dev/ttyUSB1` instead of fake `/dev/usbDev`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer you're looking for is here: [Using a USB winmodem with a Conexant driver in (K)Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1903439).

**Important stuff (extracted from the site):**

When I plugged a Conexant modem, I executed

```
lsusb
```

and it said:

[...]

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0572:1300 Conexant Systems (Rockwell), Inc. SoftK56 Data Fax Voice CARP
```

[...]

so I knew that the HSF modem was recognized by the system.

As I had a previous internet connection, I upgraded the system

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I checked that I had no previous Conexant drivers installed. For example: I executed

```
ls /usr/sbin/hsfconfig
```

and it said that that file did not exist; if it existed I would have thought that something was still installed.

I made sure that I had "gcc" and "make" ready, executing

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make
```

Then I executed those steps told there:

```
sudo -s
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux
ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h
ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h
exit
```

I prepared the files for the driver compilation, executing

```
mkdir ~/conexant_modem
cd ~/conexant_modem
```

and if I had a 64-bit operating system I executed

```
wget http://linux.dell.com/files/ubuntu/hardy/modem-drivers/hsf/hsfmodem-7.68.00.09x86_64oem.tar.gz
tar xzf hsfmodem-7.68.00.09x86_64oem.tar.gz
wget http://www.bargweb.net/images/2009/november/hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition.zip
unzip hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition.zip
cp -a hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition/modules/imported/include/framewrk.h hsfmodem-7.68.00.09x86_64oem/modules/imported/include/framewrk.h
cp -a hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition/modules/imported/include/osservices.h hsfmodem-7.68.00.09x86_64oem/modules/imported/include/osservices.h
```

else, if I had a 32-bit operating system I executed

```
wget http://linux.dell.com/files/ubuntu/hardy/modem-drivers/hsf/hsfmodem-7.68.00.09oem.tar.gz
tar xzf hsfmodem-7.68.00.09oem.tar.gz
wget http://www.bargweb.net/images/2009/november/hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition.zip
unzip hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition.zip
cp -a hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition/modules/imported/include/framewrk.h hsfmodem-7.68.00.09oem/modules/imported/include/framewrk.h
cp -a hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition/modules/imported/include/osservices.h hsfmodem-7.68.00.09oem/modules/imported/include/osservices.h
A note for the curious ones: those "framewrk.h" and "osservices.h" files were the different ones between the directories "hsfmodem-7.68.00.09oem/modules/imported" and "hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition/modules/imported".
```

If I had a 64-bit operating system I executed

```
wget http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/full/archive/hsfmodem-7.80.02.06x86_64full/hsfmodem-7.80.02.06x86_64full.tar.gz
```

else, if I had a 32-bit operating system I executed

```
wget http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/full/archive/hsfmodem-7.80.02.06full/hsfmodem-7.80.02.06full.tar.gz
```

A note for the curious ones: that file was the newest one in http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/full/downloads.php

And then, if I had a 64-bit operating system I executed

```
tar xzf hsfmodem-7.80.02.06x86_64full.tar.gz
rm -r hsfmodem-7.80.02.06x86_64full/modules/imported
cp -R hsfmodem-7.68.00.09x86_64oem/modules/imported hsfmodem-7.80.02.06x86_64full/modules/
cp -R hsfmodem-7.68.00.09x86_64oem/modules/imported hsfmodem-7.80.02.06x86_64full/modules/
```

else, if I had a 32-bit operating system I executed

```
tar xzf hsfmodem-7.80.02.06full.tar.gz
rm -r hsfmodem-7.80.02.06full/modules/imported
cp -R hsfmodem-7.68.00.09oem/modules/imported hsfmodem-7.80.02.06full/modules/
cp -R hsfmodem-7.68.00.09oem/modules/imported hsfmodem-7.80.02.06full/modules/
```

The next step was to clean the present directory.

If I had a 64-bit operating system I executed

```
rm -rf hsfmodem-7.68.00.09x86_64oem
rm -rf hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition
rm hsfmodem-7.68.00.09x86_64oem.tar.gz
rm hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition.zip
rm hsfmodem-7.80.02.06x86_64full.tar.gz
```

else, if I had a 32-bit operating system I executed

```
rm -rf hsfmodem-7.68.00.09oem
rm -rf hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition
rm hsfmodem-7.68.00.09oem.tar.gz
rm hsfmodem-7.80.02.05-DiacoEdition.zip
rm hsfmodem-7.80.02.06full.tar.gz
```

Then I had to change some files to adapt them to work with the 3.0.0 version of the Linux kernel. 
If I had a 64-bit operating system I executed

```
cd hsfmodem-7.80.02.06x86_64full
xdg-open modules/GPL/serial_cnxt.c
```

else, if I had a 32-bit operating system I executed

```
cd hsfmodem-7.80.02.06full
xdg-open modules/GPL/serial_cnxt.c
```

and then a text editor was launched. I searched for the string

```
#ifndef FOUND_UART_REGISTER_PORT
```

and below I found the string

```
static DECLARE_MUTEX(cnxt_port_sem);
```

I deleted that last string, and wrote there

```
static DEFINE_SEMAPHORE(cnxt_port_sem);
```

and I saved and closed that file. I executed

```
xdg-open modules/osdiag.c
```

and then a text editor was launched. I searched for the string

```
THIS_MODULE,
```

and below I found the string

```
.ioctl    = diag_ioctl,
```

I deleted that string, and wrote there

```
.compat_ioctl = diag_ioctl,
```

and I saved and closed that file. I executed

```
xdg-open modules/osnvm.c
```

and then a text editor was launched. I searched for the string

```
static LIST_HEAD(nvm_newinst_list);
```

and below I found the string

```
static DECLARE_MUTEX(nvmelem_writelist_sem);
```

I deleted that last string, and wrote there

```
static DEFINE_SEMAPHORE(nvmelem_writelist_sem);
```

and I saved and closed that file.

A note for the curious ones: the source of those changes in those files was http://www.openmamba.org/showfile.ht...l-2.6.37.patch

The user named Chiaseth helped telling those steps that I followed, this way:

1. I executed

   xdg-open modules/osservices.c

and then a text editor was launched. I searched for the string

```
#include <linux/smp_lock.h>
```

and I deleted that string, and wrote there

```
#include <linux/mutex.h>
DEFINE_MUTEX(os_mutex);  // Define a mutex
```

In that file I searched for the strings

```
unlock_kernel()
```

replacing all of them with

```
mutex_unlock(&os_mutex)
```

Also, in that file I searched for the strings

```
lock_kernel()
```

replacing all of them with

```
mutex_lock(&os_mutex)
```

and I saved and closed that file.

1. I executed

   xdg-open modules/osdcp.c

In that file I searched for the string

```
static spinlock_t dcp_lock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
```

replacing it with

```
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(dcp_lock);
```

and I saved and closed that file.

1. I executed

   xdg-open modules/osdiag.c

In that file I searched for the string

```
static spinlock_t diag_lock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
```

replacing it with

```
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(diag_lock);
```

and I saved and closed that file.

1. I executed

   xdg-open modules/osfloat.c

In that file I searched for the string

```
static spinlock_t fpstates_lock __attribute__((unused)) = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
```

replacing it with

```
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(fpstates_lock);
```

and I saved and closed that file.

1. I executed

   xdg-open modules/osservices.c

In that file I searched for the string

```
static spinlock_t atomic_lock __attribute__((unused)) = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
```

replacing it with

```
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(atomic_lock);
```

and I saved and closed that file.

1. I executed

   xdg-open modules/GPL/oscompat.h

In that file I searched for the string

```
static spinlock_t tqueue_lock __attribute__((unused)) = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
```

replacing it with

```
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(tqueue_lock);
```

and I saved and closed that file.

Finally...
If executed

```
sudo make install
sudo hsfconfig
```

It asked "Where is the linux source build directory that matches your running kernel?", then I simply pressed the return key to accept the default answer. I also accepted the default answer in other questions.

Finally the command reported that

```
The /dev/modem alias (symlink) points to ttySHSF0
```

I executed

```
dmesg
```

and at the end I saw

```
[59190.782005] hsfengine: module license 'see LICENSE file distributed with driver' taints kernel.
[59190.782011] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[59192.564398] ttySHSF0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 0) is a Conexant HSF softmodem (USB-0572:1300)
[59192.600274] usbcore: registered new interface driver hsfusbcd2
[59194.416241] usbcore: deregistering interface driver hsfusbcd2
[59194.600064] usb 6-1: reset full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
[59194.811746] cnxthsf_DcpDestroy: units still active, waiting..
[59194.811764] cnxthsf_DcpDestroy: units still active, waiting..
[59194.811778] cnxthsf_DcpDestroy: units still active, waiting..
[59196.967466] ttySHSF0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 0) is a Conexant HSF softmodem (USB-0572:1300)
[59196.994150] usbcore: registered new interface driver hsfusbcd2
```

which meant, among other things, that the USB modem was detected at `/dev/ttySHSF0`.

Note: as they said in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Di...Howto/Conexant: "do not delete or move the source tree [in our case: ~/conexant_modem] from your system after these steps, it will be required to uninstall and patch the driver."

I launched `kppp` (for example) and configured a new "connection", specifying that the modem was at `/dev/ttySHSF0`. You could also use a program like `efax-gtk` to send faxes through the modem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that your USB modem is properly inserted into any available USB port on your Ubuntu computer.
2. Click the network icon and select `Edit connections`. This will launch Ubuntu's networking management utility.
3. Select the name of the USB modem from the list of available connections, then click `Properties.`
4. Click `Enable this Connection` to tell Ubuntu that you want to use this device to connect to Internet networks.
5. Click `OK.` Your USB modem will now be properly connected to and configured in Ubuntu, and you can now use it to connect to the Internet.

Source of tutorial [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_6143449_connect-usb-modem-ubuntu.html#ixzz27T1ApBHW)

Answer (score 0):

There are two software I know of you can use to send AT(Attention) commands to your modem one is Serial port terminal and other one is Cutecom.