# Conexant Modem running under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, usb, modem

I've bought a USB 56k Dailup-Modem for using HylaFax later on.
The Modem gets recognized by the system via `lsusb` as follows:

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0572:1329 Conexant Systems (Rockwell), Inc.
```

But it doesn't seems to be mounted at `/dev`.

Do I need drivers for this one? If so, how do I compile them? All drivers I found were for old kernels. And I wasn't able to compile them.

Comment: One question only, please.

Comment: Done so. Changed my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/192717/how-to-talk-to-usb-modem-in-linux